# Hive join with duplicate keys

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have two tables like

table 1:

```
c_id,   p_id,   sales  
x,   1, 1  
x,  2,  1  
x,  3,  1  
x,  4,  1  
y,  5,  1  
y,  4,  1  
y,  3,  1  
y,  6,  1  
y,  7,  1  
z,  1,  1  
z,  8,  1
```

Table 2:

```
c_id,   p_id,   sales  
x,  8,  1  
x,  2,  1  
x,  7,  1  
y,  5,  1  
y,  2,  1  
y,  3,  1  
z,  3,  1
```

I want to get c_id and p_id pairs which are present in table2 but not in table1. so the result should look like:

```
c_id    p_id    sales  
x,  8,  1  
x,  7,  1  
y,  2,  1  
z,  3,  1
```

I used the following code but it does not work:

```
select b.c_id, b.p_id, b.sales  
from table1 as a  
join table2 as b  
on a.c_id = b.c_id
where a.p_id != b.p_id
```

thanks

Comment: @jarlh: thanks for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `left join` and then check for no matches:

```
select b.c_id, b.p_id, b.sales
from table2 b left join
     table1 a
     on a.c_id = b.c_id and a.p_id = b.p_id
where a.c_id is null;
```